# Cannot Connect Path Points with Line Renderer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to generate a pathway system where a line is being rendered with time. My code is:

```
public IEnumerator DrawPath(List<Vector3> pathWay)
    {

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;

        points = new Vector3[pathWay.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < pathWay.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 checkpointpos = pathWay[i];
            points[i] = new Vector3(checkpointpos.x, checkpointpos.y, checkpointpos.z);
        }


        lineRenderer.startWidth = 1f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 1f;
        lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            //Mathf.Lerp
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, points[i]);
        }
        
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

I am getting `List<Vector3>` from A* Pathfinding free version plugin.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand your problem, what do you want in result?

Comment: @Frenchy if you see in gif output there is weird line coming from top and connecting with each other. I dont want that.

Comment: so could you display the different values of your points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I resolved the issue.

The problem was setting the counts of lines all at once so whenever I was setting a new vector it starts from position 0 that's why I had problem.

**Solution:**

```
 public IEnumerator DrawPath(List<Vector3> pathWay)
    {

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        points = new Vector3[pathWay.Count];

        lineRenderer.startWidth = 1f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 1f;

        for (int i = 0; i < pathWay.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 checkpointpos = pathWay[i];
            points[i] = new Vector3(checkpointpos.x, checkpointpos.y, checkpointpos.z);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            lineRenderer.positionCount++;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, points[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]